# how '+' operator works in the c codesample?

Tags: c

I run this c code . and gives result without error. but i don't understand how does the code gives this result .what is the hidden working process? my thought is that normal sign multiplication works here . is it true?
**c language code sample is given below:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    printf("%d ", + +9);
    printf("%d ", + -9);
    printf("%d ", - +9);
    printf("%d ", - -9);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
9 -9 -9 9

Comment: Would it make more sense to you parenthesized as `printf("%d ", + (+9));` etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden working process"? This is basic math they teach in primary school.

Answer (score 1):

`+ + 9` is parsed as `+` applied to `+ 9`, and the latter is `+` applied to `9`. The unary `+` operator produces the value of its operand. So `+` applied to 9 gives 9, and `+` applied to that also gives 9.

The next two cases are fairly simple, so I will discuss the last one, `- - 9`. This is `-` applied to `- 9`, and the latter is `-` applied to `9`. The unary `-` operator produces the negative of its operand. So `-` applied to 9 gives −9, and `-` applied to −9 gives 9.